# Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. I am creating a notes app

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDKki.png)

Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.

```
enter code here
package com.example.notes

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface NoteDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(note: Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(note: Note)

    @Query("Select * from notes_table order by id ASC")
    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>
}

    Code for Entity
package com.example.notes

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
class Note(@ColumnInfo(name = "text")val text: String,){
           @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id= 0
}
```

Comment: Please post source code of your entity and DAO

Comment: I have posted the code for DAO

Answer (score 0):

based on your code , your entity class is Wrong

your entity class must be `data class` and add table column filed inside constructor

The following code is an example of a simple entity that defines a User table with columns for ID, first name, and last name:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val firstName: String?,
    val lastName: String?
)
```

so your entity class must be :

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

no need to add `@ColumnInfo` for table column that has same name as variable name and `autoGenerate = true` cause of that its true by defualt

Comment: I used your code but still getting the same error

Comment: What room version are you using?